# Intellij doesn't generate .gitignore file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I configured my ignored files through "Settings->version control->ignored files", but didn't see the .gitignore file to be created. Should I create it manually? Or

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support managing `.gitignore` files. Vote for [this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60354).

You can use [.ignore plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore) for assistance with managing the `.gitignore` file directly from the IDE.

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 has added native `.gitignore` support. You can find more information in [their blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/07/support-for-vcs-ignores-in-intellij-idea-and-intellij-based-ides/).

For older versions, you can use the [.ignore plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore) for assistance.